# Why bhagavatam is authentic for Iskcon?

Tags: puranas, iskcon, prabhupada, interpolation

Why iskcon is taking bhagavatam as authentic other then Vishnu Purana and Shiva Purana and skanda Purana ?

Do iskcon consider other then bhagavatam all puranas are  interpolated

Comment: As far as I know, ISKCON doesn't understand it to interpolated. But ISKCON accept Srimad Bhagavatam as final conclusion of all Vedas, and Upanishads, and Puranas. Also as per verse in Padma Purana, there is division of Purana based on modes of material nature, Sattva, Rajas, and Tamo Guna, that is for people predominantly in that modes of material nature. But Srimad Bhagavatam to transcendental and above or beyond all material things.

Comment: A sect is to be based on a scripture always. You're basically asking , equivalently, why Hindus follow the Vedas and not the Bible. It's all about ideologies and beliefs.

Comment: Iskcon follows gudiya parampara/ sampradaya where Srimad Bhagavatam is considered the highest of all scriptures as so claimed by Lord Shi Chaitnya Mahaprabhu who was an Yuga Avatar of Sri Krishna himself. Iskcon does refer scriptures like Vishnu Purana, Skand Puran and other satvik Purans which are followed in the Sampradaya.

Comment: Well, the Bhagavatam is the self-prophesied greatest Purana. Without anything to the contrary, I don't see why not to believe that.

Comment: Means other puranas are waste according to Iskcon

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud The other puranas are not a waste. Srimad Bhagavatam is just the culmination of all the puranas, for it describes the highest goal of life.

Comment: OK I believe that bhagavatam is high

Comment: What about other puranas

Answer (score 1):

Because Srimad Bhagvatam itself Declared it the Greatest and same thing is confirmed in Garud Puran, Padma Puran, Skanda Puran, Matsya Puran etc.    This is also confirmed by Acharyas of all 4 Vaishnav Sampradayas.

Srimad Bhagvatam is considered Greatest in all 4 Vaishnav Sampradayas and their Shakhas be if Madhva Sampradaya, Gaudiya Sampradaya, Vadakalai Sri Vaishnavas, Thenkalai Sri Vaishnava, Ramanandi Vaishnavas, Nimbarkacharya Sampradaya, Vallabhacharya Sampradaya and also it is the Opinion of Sripad Sridhar Swami.

We refer to other Puranas also but the Central emphasis is on Bhagvatam and anything which Contradicts Bhagvatam should be either Reconsiled or if un reconsilable then it should be understood to be for Bewilderment and not the ultimate Conclusion.

Coming to Interpolation, it is a fact that many Scriptures have been Interpolated over time so we don't have to Focus on that.  Generally it is observed the Bhagvatam, Narad Puran, Matsya Puran, Vishnu Puran did not suffer Interpolation, rest may have some but that is not the Concern, we accept whatever is in line with Bhagvatam

Comment: Please provide references for the statements in your answer.